# When someone likes an article on my blog, they are prompted to log in on Wordpress.com

Tags: themes, login, plugin-jetpack

I've set up a blog (not a wordpress.com one) on a regular hosting service. I've installed a free theme and jetpack.

The problem is, when someone attempts to like a post, they are prompted to log in to WordPress.com.

Any clue on how to solve this? I don't get why users should be prompted to login to wordpress when they want to like an article.

**Later edit:** I am interested in the regular facebook 'like' and if this comes with JetPack.  If not, are there any popular and easy-to-use plugins?

Comment: What type of "like" system are you referring to? Is it the wordpress.com like system? Facebook Likes? Or does your theme have it's own like plugin running?

Comment: After doing some reading I realized it's the wordpress.com 'like' system (which is the one that comes with jetpack. Again, this is from what I've read and I might be wrong). What I am interested in is the facebook like. Is it possible to get this from jetpack ?

Comment: It's actually a WordPress.com "like" &mdash; enabled by JetPack. If you want to enable a Facebook "like", that will also require a Facebook login. If you want to make a custom "like" button specially for your blog &mdash; that's a different issue. Please confirm first.

Comment: I've edited my question. If it's unclear, I'm be interested in the kind of like that would check if the user is already logged on facebook. If not, it will log him/her in first (obviously with their provided credentials), then 'execute' the like.

Comment: There are plenty of Facebook plugins out there that allow Facebook 'like' of blogs or articles. Just search for Facebook or social sharing plugins in the Wordpress library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A user must have a Wordpress.com account to use the Jetpack like function.

> It’s worth noting that you readers will need to log in to their WordPress.com account to be able to Like one of your posts.

[Jetpack website: Likes](http://jetpack.me/support/likes/)

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer. Do you know any alternative for this then? all i want is to be able to let users like my posts (facebook like, not the wordpress one)

Comment: There are many voting/rating plugins out there. I use [WTI Like post](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wti-like-post/)